# Is it possible to limit how many goroutines run per second?

Tags: http, go

I have a list of URLs that I need to use goroutine to fire off HTTP requests concurrently. Is there anyway to check and limit how many of those HTTP requests are sent per second?

Comment: Go can't globally limit goroutines. If you're making the http requests, can't you limit them yourself?

Comment: @JimB: How should I go about limiting them? For example, I would like the program to send less than or equal to 10 http requests per second.

Comment: Use can use a semaphore to limit maximum concurrent requests, and/or use a rate limiting algorithm like a [token bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) or [leaky bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A very simple version of this in Go would be an adaptation of a [Leaky Bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket) algorithm, using a channel and a goroutine. Receiving a token from the `rate` channel before making a request will check the rate and block if the rate limiter is empty.

```
// create a buffered channel.
// The capacity of the channel is maximum burst that can be made.
rate := make(chan struct{}, 10)

go func() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millisecond)
    for range ticker.C {
        rate <- struct{}{}
    }
}()
```

Since a series of requests that take longer than the average rate will end up being concurrent, you may need to limit concurrency too. You can add a second channel as a semaphore, adding a token to the semaphore before making a request, and removing it when it's complete.

```
// limit concurrency to 5
semaphore := make(chan struct{}, 5)

// in request function
semaphore <- struct{}{}
defer func() {
    <-semaphore
}()
```

A slightly more complete example is here:

https://play.golang.org/p/ZrTPLcdeDF

Comment: We could reverse the direction the channel is used, that is, the generator would send values on it and the requests would receive from it. That way you do not need to fill it initially.

Comment: Yup, I think I was just translating the algorithm literally at the time. Thanks!

Comment: If you need more control/features there is a token bucket implementation at [`golang.org/x/time/rate`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/time/rate).

Comment: The "slightly more complete example" from this answer using `golang.org/x/time/rate`: https://play.golang.org/p/44rUKLdTPbO

Comment: @JimB is there a reason you're using a struct for the channel instead of an int?

Comment: @DaveC in your "slightly more complete example", why are you using the limiter and the semaphore? Doesn't the limiter do it all?

Comment: @jshen (Note: it's bit a long time since I wrote that, I think I was mostly copying/translating from Jim's example.) The limiter only limits the rate at which new requests can be started, if requests are long lived (e.g. if the "added token" print was replaced with real work such an HTTP request like in the OP) there is no limit to how many can end up concurrently running. Either a semaphore or a worker pool are easy ways to limit this. Typically I'd use a worker pool instead of a semaphore but which is better depends on the problem and usage specifics.

Comment: @jshen: using an `int` implies that the value of the `int` has meaning, which it doesn't. The empty `struct{}` is more obviously just an opaque token.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simple package to help you limit the number of goroutines that are allowed to run concurrently. Please check https://github.com/zenthangplus/goccm

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "goccm"
    "time"
)

func main()  {
    // Limit 3 goroutines to run concurrently.
    c := goccm.New(3)

    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {

        // This function have to call before any goroutine
        c.Wait()

        go func(i int) {
            fmt.Printf("Job %d is running\n", i)
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

            // This function have to when a goroutine has finished
            // Or you can use `defer c.Done()` at the top of goroutine.
            c.Done()
        }(i)
    }

    // This function have to call to ensure all goroutines have finished 
    // after close the main program.
    c.WaitAllDone()
}
```