# Creating a Synchronous Rate Limiter

Tags: go, channel, rate-limiting

I am emulating a request process where I have a synchronous rate limiter (in the form of a channel with cap == number of items to be limited on). The desired rate limit is 1 request per 1 second.

The issue I believe is that I am using a blocking `for` and not a goroutine, however my desired goal is to emulate this process synchronously.

I desire that I notify my channel that an operation is being performed (the print statement in my code example), and until that is complete and finished. I'd like to make sure that if the operation succeeded in < 1 second. I wait the difference until I send the next `for` iteration.

Perhaps a channel is overkill since I'm not using goroutines here and I should do some time measuring at the start of each iteration and after each response is received to `time.Sleep()` for the difference? Is there a better way?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Data struct {
    Field1 string
    Ch     chan struct{}
}

func main() {
    data := &Data{
        Field1: "hello world",
        Ch:     make(chan struct{}, 1),
    }

    // fill up our data channel bucket
    for i := 0; i < cap(data.Ch); i++ {
        data.Ch <- struct{}{}
    }
    defer close(data.Ch)

    // create goroutine to attempt to do something every 1 second
    go func() {
        ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
        defer ticker.Stop()
        for range ticker.C {
            _, ok := <-data.Ch
            if !ok {
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    count := 0
    for {
        if count == 10 {
            fmt.Println("breaking the loop!")
            break
        }

        // place token into channel to signal we are performing an operation
        data.Ch <- struct{}{}

        // do things
        fmt.Printf("hello user! it is: %s o clock!\n", time.Now().UTC().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z07:00"))

        // remove token in channel so we can do more operations
        <-data.Ch
        count++
    }
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789362/is-it-possible-to-limit-how-many-goroutines-run-per-second/43792222#43792222

Comment: @JimB yeah. you're right. I was reading items in my ticker incorrectly.

Comment: @JimB to be sure I understand. in your other answer. you are filling up your channel to max capacity, then spawning a goroutine that will read items from the channel every 100 ms. then in your goroutines you fill the bucket up by placing a token in the bucket? if the channel is still full (meaning we shouldn't make another request), it will block until there is room in the bucket?

Comment: Yes, that is the basics of the [leaky bucket algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket). The space available in the channel is set at your rate limit.

Comment: @JimB excellent stuff. I am learning so much about channels every day thanks to your contributions here.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be doing this backwards. If you want a simple rate limiter using a channel, then have a goroutine that fills the channel at a given rate:

```
go func() {
        ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
        defer ticker.Stop()
        for range ticker.C {
            select {
             case data.Ch<-struct{}{}:
             default:
            }
        }
}()
```

Then, consume from the channel to rate limit:

```
for {
  <-data.Ch
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: I see. so this will block until a new item is ready to be consumed from the channel (which happens at most, every 1s), preventing us from exceeding the rate limit. This makes a lot of sense. thanks.

Comment: To increase burstiness increase channel buffer size.